# Simplifying an algorithm to evaluate $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n(x_i\&x_j)(x_j|x_k)$ for non-negative integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ sequence of non-negative integers. I need to calculate $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_i \& x_j)(x_j | x_k)$$
Here "$\&$" stands for bitwise AND, and "$|$" stands for bitwise OR

I know how to write an algorithm that runs ~ $O(n^3)$. How can you get rid of the triple amount?

Comment: You can take a look at here just for your reference. https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/86126/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to take a look at these two
https://codeforces.com/contest/1466/problem/E
https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/86126/

Answer (score -1):

Here's a hint. Let $f(a,b) = x_a \wedge x_b$ and $g(a,b) = x_a \vee x_b$. You are asked to compute
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n f(i,j) g(j,k) = \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n f(i,j) g(j,k) \right).
$$

The straightforward way is to do $O(n^3)$ ANDs, ORs, multiplications and additions.
How can you  simply speed up the computation just by manipulating the above formula?